# Sticky session behind proxy for two apps

Tags: f5, sticky-session

He have two web apps: app A and app B. They are both installed in server 1 and server 2 (so one instance of A in server 1, one instance of A in server 2. same for app B). App A navigates to app B via SSO.
We use F5 load balancer to distribute the requests, and we are not sure on how to implement the sticky session in that case, as first, we cannot do IP based, as the are behind a reverse proxy, hence, the IP would always be the same.
Also, seems like the cookie option does not working when navigating from app A to app B.
(I am not a load balancer specialist... hopefully, I provided all info required).
Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. 
Design as below

```
 ---------------             server 1
| load balancer | ---->      App A ->(SSO)-> App B
 ---------------
                             server 2
                             App A ->(SSO)-> App B
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Thais;  How are the applications accessed?  Do they just use separate ports on the same address or do they use different urls to access?  This will determine how the F5 BIG-IP should be setup by your network/application team.

Comment: In some cases (depending on your client), [SSL persistence](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K3062) could be the solution.

Comment: Hi Chase, they are on the same address.
Hi Eugene, 
Will try to explore this option with the team. Might take a few days, but will let you know later if worked.
Thank you both for your attention on this. :-)

Comment: Hi  Eugène, 
As per the article, there can be some issues related to IE versions. 
I tried some researches, but I didn't find anything very clear about it so far. Would you know if IE9+ would have issues regarding to force SSL session ID renegotiation at very short intervals?

Comment: @ThaisMKManfrin (you need to add @ before the name if you want to notify anyone). Usually the cookie persistence works but maybe are you loosing the cookie for any reason and you need to take a trace to understand what's happening. I suggested the SSL persistence because I thought App A was a "real" app, not something run from a browser. If you only have server 1 and server 2, what are the benefits of persistence ?

Comment: Hi @Eugène Adell, 
I edited the original post to make clearer that I am working with two web apps.  They are both in server 1 and server 2. We need to guarantee all subsequent requests after login go to same server (server 1 or 2), otherwise the user will be logged out of the app, hence the need for the sticky session.